# Fastest way to handle an ItemIterator

Tags: python, tweepy, tweets

Basically I am using Tweepy to fetch the user whole tweeter timeline, using Cursor:

```
tweets_timeline = tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,id=user_id, tweet_mode="extended").items()
```

That gives me an ItemIterator, witch, depending on the user, can have more than 3500 items. By doing some work trough those items with a function, its taking me close to a minute, I am trying to speed up the process.

Ive tried multiprocessing this task, like so:

```
executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(10)
future = [executor.submit(task, args) for tweet in tweets_timeline]
concurrent.futures.wait(future)
```

But it doesn't seem to neither be  working nor be the optimal solution.

Is there a correct way of speeding up the process?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Twitter might intentionally limit API calls to avoid getting flooded with requests, so you might be out of luck without breaking their TOS.

Comment: Thank you very much! When I try just fetching the tweets, the first line of code, it process immediately. Is it really the case of tweeter API limits?

Comment: It probably fetches it lazily, meaning it won't download the actual tweets until you process them, but that is just a guess